# How to specify an absolute distance between (header) text and the start of the (header) line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, fancyhdr

Currently I am trying to align the text of the header with the main text, while the page number is shifted 25 pt into the margin (see image). I have tried different things, like using the \tabto package (which works for page number in the left margin) and using a table. Thus far without any success.

[image]

It is possible to specify an absolute distance between the header text and the start of the header line? Which should be, in the following example, 25 pt. The page number and header text should be right-aligned.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clears all header and footer fields.
\fancyhead[RO]{\normalsize \sffamily header text \thepage}% Displays the lower-level (chapter) information in the header, to the left on even pages.

% allow headers to stick out of margin
\fancyheadoffset[RO]{25pt} 

% underlining of headers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.25pt}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\Blindtext
\Blindtext
\section{Second Section}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily header text\makebox[25pt][r]{\thepage}}
```

[image]